# Path expected for join

Tags: java, sql, jpa, repository

Entity relationship between Asset, pstupdatefile and checkedouthistory When trying to join these am getting the error message path expected for join

```
here am adding my entities and db query

@Entity
@Table(name = "POST_UPDATE_FILE")
public class PostUpdateFile implements java.io.Serializable {

    private int postUpdateFileId;
    private Reason reasonByReasonForReprocessing;
    private Reason reasonByReasonForFailure;
    private Package softwarePackage;
    private Asset asset;
    private String upgradeStatus;
    private boolean manuallyProcessed;
    private String eventLogfileId;
    private String comment;
    private boolean operationManualHandover;
    private Date updatedOn;
    private String updatedBy;
    private Date processedOn;
    private String processedBy;
    private String fileSource;
    private String previousVersion;
    private String currentVersion;
    private Set<PostUpdateRetryCount> postUpdateRetryCounts = new HashSet<>(0);

    @Id

    @Column(name = "POST_UPDATE_FILE_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public int getPostUpdateFileId() {
        return this.postUpdateFileId;
    }

    public void setPostUpdateFileId(int postUpdateFileId) {
        this.postUpdateFileId = postUpdateFileId;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "REASON_FOR_REPROCESSING")
    public Reason getReasonByReasonForReprocessing() {
        return this.reasonByReasonForReprocessing;
    }

    public void setReasonByReasonForReprocessing(Reason reasonByReasonForReprocessing) {
        this.reasonByReasonForReprocessing = reasonByReasonForReprocessing;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "REASON_FOR_FAILURE")
    public Reason getReasonByReasonForFailure() {
        return this.reasonByReasonForFailure;
    }

    public void setReasonByReasonForFailure(Reason reasonByReasonForFailure) {
        this.reasonByReasonForFailure = reasonByReasonForFailure;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="PACKAGE_ID", nullable=false)
    public Package getSoftwarePackage() {
        return softwarePackage;
    }

    public void setSoftwarePackage(Package softwarePackage) {
        this.softwarePackage = softwarePackage;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ASSET_SERIAL_NUMBER", nullable = false)
    public Asset getAsset() {
        return this.asset;
    }

    public void setAsset(Asset asset) {
        this.asset = asset;
    }

    @Column(name = "UPGRADE_STATUS", length = 12)
    public String getUpgradeStatus() {
        return this.upgradeStatus;
    }

    public void setUpgradeStatus(String upgradeStatus) {
        this.upgradeStatus = upgradeStatus;
    }

    @Column(name = "MANUALLY_PROCESSED", nullable = false)
    public boolean isManuallyProcessed() {
        return this.manuallyProcessed;
    }

    public void setManuallyProcessed(boolean manuallyProcessed) {
        this.manuallyProcessed = manuallyProcessed;
    }



    @Column(name = "COMMENT", length = 512)
    public String getComment() {
        return this.comment;
    }

    public void setComment(String comment) {
        this.comment = comment;
    }

    @Column(name = "OPERATION_MANUAL_HANDOVER", nullable = false)
    public boolean isOperationManualHandover() {
        return this.operationManualHandover;
    }

    public void setOperationManualHandover(boolean operationManualHandover) {
        this.operationManualHandover = operationManualHandover;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "UPDATED_ON", nullable = false, length = 19)
    public Date getUpdatedOn() {
        return this.updatedOn;
    }

    public void setUpdatedOn(Date updatedOn) {
        this.updatedOn = updatedOn;
    }

    @Column(name = "UPDATED_BY", nullable = false, length = 12)
    public String getUpdatedBy() {
        return this.updatedBy;
    }

    public void setUpdatedBy(String updatedBy) {
        this.updatedBy = updatedBy;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "PROCESSED_ON", nullable = false, length = 19)
    public Date getProcessedOn() {
        return this.processedOn;
    }

    public void setProcessedOn(Date processedOn) {
        this.processedOn = processedOn;
    }

    @Column(name = "PROCESSED_BY", nullable = false, length = 12)
    public String getProcessedBy() {
        return this.processedBy;
    }

    public void setProcessedBy(String processedBy) {
        this.processedBy = processedBy;
    }

    @Column(name = "EVENT_LOGFILE_ID", length = 30)
    public String getEventLogfileId() {
        return this.eventLogfileId;
    }

    public void setEventLogfileId(String eventLogfileId) {
        this.eventLogfileId = eventLogfileId;
    }

    @Column(name = "FILE_SOURCE", length = 10)
    public String getFileSource() {
        return this.fileSource;
    }

    public void setFileSource(String fileSource) {
        this.fileSource = fileSource;
    }

    @Column(name = "PREVIOUS_VERSION", length = 16)
    public String getPreviousVersion() {
        return this.previousVersion;
    }

    public void setPreviousVersion(String previousVersion) {
        this.previousVersion = previousVersion;
    }

    @Column(name = "CURRENT_VERSION", length = 16)
    public String getCurrentVersion() {
        return this.currentVersion;
    }

    public void setCurrentVersion(String currentVersion) {
        this.currentVersion = currentVersion;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "postUpdateFile")
    public Set<PostUpdateRetryCount> getPostUpdateRetryCounts() {
        return this.postUpdateRetryCounts;
    }

    public void setPostUpdateRetryCounts(Set<PostUpdateRetryCount> postUpdateRetryCounts) {
        this.postUpdateRetryCounts = postUpdateRetryCounts;
    }

}



@Entity
@Table(name = "CHECK_OUT_HISTORY")
public class CheckOutHistory implements java.io.Serializable {

    private int checkOutHistoryId;
    private Package softwarePackage;
    private User user;
    private Asset asset;
    private Date checkedOutOn;

    @Id

    @Column(name = "CHECK_OUT_HISTORY_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public int getCheckOutHistoryId() {
        return this.checkOutHistoryId;
    }

    public void setCheckOutHistoryId(int checkOutHistoryId) {
        this.checkOutHistoryId = checkOutHistoryId;
    }


    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="PACKAGE_ID", nullable=false)
    public Package getSoftwarePackage() {
        return softwarePackage;
    }

    public void setSoftwarePackage(Package softwarePackage) {
        this.softwarePackage = softwarePackage;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CHECKED_OUT_BY", nullable = false)
    public User getUser() {
        return this.user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ASSET_SERIAL_NUMBER", nullable = false)
    public Asset getAsset() {
        return this.asset;
    }

    public void setAsset(Asset asset) {
        this.asset = asset;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "CHECKED_OUT_ON", nullable = false, length = 19)
    public Date getCheckedOutOn() {
        return this.checkedOutOn;
    }

    public void setCheckedOutOn(Date checkedOutOn) {
        this.checkedOutOn = checkedOutOn;
    }

}



@Entity
@Table(name = "ASSET", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "SYSTEM_ID"))
public class Asset implements java.io.Serializable {

    private String assetSerialNumber;
    private Account account;
    private Country country;
    private User energySalesPerson;
    private Product product;
    private Status status;
    private String softwareVersion;
    private boolean checkedOut;
    private int systemId;
    private Date lastUpdatedOn;
    private String lastUpdatedBy;
    private String modifiedAttributes;
    private String checkedOutBy;
    private Integer shipLocationId;
    private String sourceCountry;
    private AccountLocation accountLocation;
    private Set<CheckInHistory> checkInHistories = new HashSet<>(0);
    private Set<CheckOutHistory> checkOutHistories = new HashSet<>(0);
    private Set<PostUpdateFile> postUpdateFiles = new HashSet<>(0);
    private Set<ReassignedAsset> reassignedAssets = new HashSet<>(0);
    @Id

    @Column(name = "ASSET_SERIAL_NUMBER", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 16)
    public String getAssetSerialNumber() {
        return this.assetSerialNumber;
    }

    public void setAssetSerialNumber(String assetSerialNumber) {
        this.assetSerialNumber = assetSerialNumber;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ACCOUNT_ID")
    public Account getAccount() {
        return this.account;
    }

    public void setAccount(Account account) {
        this.account = account;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ENERGY_SALES_PERSON")
    public User getEnergySalesPerson() {
        return energySalesPerson;
    }

    public void setEnergySalesPerson(User energySalesPerson) {
        this.energySalesPerson = energySalesPerson;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "SIEBEL_PRODUCT_CODE")
    public Product getProduct() {
        return this.product;
    }

    public void setProduct(Product product) {
        this.product = product;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "LAST_UPDATED_STATUS")
    public Status getStatus() {
        return this.status;
    }

    public void setStatus(Status status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    @Column(name = "SOFTWARE_VERSION", nullable = false, length = 16)
    public String getSoftwareVersion() {
        return this.softwareVersion;
    }

    public void setSoftwareVersion(String softwareVersion) {
        this.softwareVersion = softwareVersion;
    }

    @Column(name = "CHECKED_OUT", nullable = false)
    public boolean isCheckedOut() {
        return this.checkedOut;
    }

    public void setCheckedOut(boolean checkedOut) {
        this.checkedOut = checkedOut;
    }

    @Column(name = "SYSTEM_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public int getSystemId() {
        return this.systemId;
    }

    public void setSystemId(int systemId) {
        this.systemId = systemId;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "LAST_UPDATED_ON", nullable = false, length = 19)
    public Date getLastUpdatedOn() {
        return this.lastUpdatedOn;
    }

    public void setLastUpdatedOn(Date lastUpdatedOn) {
        this.lastUpdatedOn = lastUpdatedOn;
    }

    @Column(name = "LAST_UPDATED_BY", nullable = false, length = 12)
    public String getLastUpdatedBy() {
        return this.lastUpdatedBy;
    }

    public void setLastUpdatedBy(String lastUpdatedBy) {
        this.lastUpdatedBy = lastUpdatedBy;
    }

    @Column(name = "MODIFIED_ATTRIBUTES", length = 100)
    public String getModifiedAttributes() {
        return this.modifiedAttributes;
    }

    public void setModifiedAttributes(String modifiedAttributes) {
        this.modifiedAttributes = modifiedAttributes;
    }

    @Column(name = "CHECKED_OUT_BY", length = 12)
    public String getCheckedOutBy() {
        return this.checkedOutBy;
    }

    public void setCheckedOutBy(String checkedOutBy) {
        this.checkedOutBy = checkedOutBy;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "asset")
    public Set<CheckInHistory> getCheckInHistories() {
        return this.checkInHistories;
    }

    public void setCheckInHistories(Set<CheckInHistory> checkInHistories) {
        this.checkInHistories = checkInHistories;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "asset")
    public Set<CheckOutHistory> getCheckOutHistories() {
        return this.checkOutHistories;
    }

    public void setCheckOutHistories(Set<CheckOutHistory> checkOutHistories) {
        this.checkOutHistories = checkOutHistories;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "asset")
    public Set<PostUpdateFile> getPostUpdateFiles() {
        return this.postUpdateFiles;
    }

    public void setPostUpdateFiles(Set<PostUpdateFile> postUpdateFiles) {
        this.postUpdateFiles = postUpdateFiles;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "asset")
    public Set<ReassignedAsset> getReassignedAssets() {
        return this.reassignedAssets;
    }

    public void setReassignedAssets(Set<ReassignedAsset> reassignedAssets) {
        this.reassignedAssets = reassignedAssets;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "COUNTRY_CODE")
    public Country getCountry() {
        return this.country;
    }

    public void setCountry(Country country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    @Column(name = "SHIP_LOCATION_ID")
    public Integer getShipLocationId() {
        return this.shipLocationId;
    }

    public void setShipLocationId(Integer shipLocationId) {
        this.shipLocationId = shipLocationId;
    }

    @Column(name = "SOURCE_COUNTRY", length = 32)
    public String getSourceCountry() {
        return this.sourceCountry;
    }

    public void setSourceCountry(String sourceCountry) {
        this.sourceCountry = sourceCountry;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ASSET_LOCATION_ID")
    public AccountLocation getAccountLocation() {
        return this.accountLocation;
    }

    public void setAccountLocation(AccountLocation accountLocation) {
        this.accountLocation = accountLocation;
    }

}
```

query for retrieving the data.its always returning   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Path expected for join!

```
  select puf.processedOn,coh.checkedOutOn from Asset a inner join PostUpdateFile puf on a.assetSerialNumber=puf.assetSerialNumber inner join CheckOutHistory coh on a.assetSerialNumber=coh.assetSerialNumber where a.assetSerialNumber=:assetno
```

Comment: What is the entity relationship between `process`, `processupdatefile` and `processupdatefile`? Can you post your entities? HQL join require a path from one entity to the other.

Comment: Can you update your question instead of put into comments?

Comment: JOIN should be followed by a RELATION. It currently isn't

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Path expected for join!
```

The above exception is talking about `join` should use a `path` from one entity to other defined in the mapping.

Your entities show that `CheckOutHistory` and `ProcessUpdateFile` are collection members of `ASSET`.

Instead of

```
from Asset a
inner join processupdatefile puf
```

We need a `path` from `ASSET` to `ProcessUpdateFile`, i.e.

```
from Asset a
inner join a.postUpdateFiles puf
```

The HQL should look like:

```
select 
    puf.processedOn,
    coh.checkedOutOn 
from Asset a 
inner join a.postUpdateFiles puf 
    on a.assetSerialNumber = puf.assetSerialNumber 
inner join a.checkOutHistories coh 
    on a.assetSerialNumber = coh.assetSerialNumber 
where a.assetSerialNumber =: assetno
```